# Display absolute value angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am getting a negative number from JSON object. I want to remove "-" form that negative number and only display the absolute value.

Received json:

```
{
    "value": -2.34
}
```

What I want to show:

> The value is: 2.34

Comment: Try `Math.abs(-2.34);`

Comment: In your case - is not a symbol. Its a sign.

Comment: Your question has changed, namely, the number format. In this regard, you can rewrite the filter like this `return function(num) { return Math.abs(num.value) }` and after that use it in html such way `{{ {"value": "-2.34"} | makePositive }}`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use angular filter

js file

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).filter('makePositive', function() {
    return function(num) { return Math.abs(num); }
});
```

html file

```
{{ (-12) | makePositive }}
{{ (2) | makePositive }}
```

output

12 2

Answer (score 8):

You can use JavaScript supported built-in [Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) object for getting absolute value.

```
Math.abs(-2.34)
```

> The Math.abs() function returns the absolute value of a number

**[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs)**

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.abs(number)
```

This will get you the absolute value of any number you put in there, including the removal of any leading zeroes.

Additionally, you can also do this:

```
parseInt(number, 10)
```